# what latex package should i use to get these diagrams?

Tags: diagrams, grids, feynman

im trying to use latex to draw out diagrams from lambda phi 4 theory and they look a bit like this:

[image]

[image]

what packages do I use to achieve drawings like this? and how exactly do i do it? I'm really new to latex and I'm  so confused

Comment: It's always best to show some effort from your end rather than requesting the community to do things for you, even if you're new to the environment.

Comment: @Werner my apologies, i should've phrased my question better. i just wanted recommendations that's all.

Comment: I suggest to use feynmp package.

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages for drawing Feynman diagrams:  https://ctan.org/search?phrase=feynman

tikz-feynman seems to be quite versatile and easy to use.